# Nginx location redirect but saving the arguments passed

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect users to a new URL while preserving the URL query parameters. I'm trying this, which doesn't pass the URL params:

```
location = /api/redirects {
  return 301 /api2/redirects;
}
```

```
https://example.com/api/redirects?param=1&anotherParam=10

  => https://example.com/api2/redirects
```

I also tried:

```
location = /api/redirects {
  return 301 /api2/redirects$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: Did you restart Nginx after making the configuration change and did you **reset the browser cache**. Your `$is_args$args` fix should work. Rather than relying on the browser, test it using `curl -I http://example.com/api/redirects`

Comment: @LearningPath In opposite to `return` directive, `rewrite` one will preserve any existing query arguments: `rewrite ^ /api2/redirects permanent;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`rewrite`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite)  explicitly outside of a `location` block. RegEx parentheses can capture URI values after `/api/` as `$1`.  The query string is always passed in a `rewrite` directive.

```
# 302 Moved Temporarily
rewrite ^/api/(redirects.*) /api2/$1 redirect;
```

```
# 301 Moved Permanently
rewrite ^/api/(redirects.*) /api2/$1 permanent;
```